# How to confirm payload fairing seperation

Tags: fairings, payload-deployment, separation

How do launch providers confirm fairing separation? I know they have a video feed, but I assume there's a more reliable (short delay) means of detecting separation. Is it as simple as a limit switch?

Comment: Could be a switch, but I would guess they also look for what should be a pretty instantaneous increase in acceleration. Even if it's just a slight increase I would think it would be noticeable.

Comment: Also, break in data from (pressure, temperature, vibration) sensors installed on the fairing.

Comment: Not only a mechanical switch but also magnetic or optic sensors for the presence or absence of the fairing.

Comment: It's very often even simpler than a switch -- breakwires are pretty typical for these.

Comment: Yes, those are really good methods. How about confirming that they have cleared the path of the rocket and not just opened? Or is that a bit of a stretch without visual confirmation? I guess you'd know (i.e. failure to deploy payload, accelerometer spiking = body strike).